# Proving a sequence converges by the definition of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Consider the sequence $\frac{3n}{2n+1}$ from $n=1$ to $\infty$.

The definition of convergence says that for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exist a positive integer $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$ we have that $|a_n - A| < \epsilon$.

For this problem, is it sufficient to let $N=\frac{3}{4\epsilon}$?

Comment: Yes, that works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You have to state what the limit converges to before you can start proving this. In this case you want $A=\frac 32$.

Let's work forward before writing a proof. We want $$\left|\frac {3n}{2n+1} - \frac 32\right| < \epsilon.$$ Simplifying the LHS, we get $\left|\frac{(3n)(2) -(3)(2n+1)}{4n+2}\right| = \left|\frac{3}{4n+2}\right|<\epsilon$. Since the value inside the absolute value is positive, we can write $\frac 3 \epsilon < 4n + 2$, or in simpler terms $\frac 14 \left ( \frac 3 \epsilon - 2\right)< n$.

Now we can write our proof:

Let $N =  \left\lceil \frac 14 \left ( \frac 3 \epsilon - 2\right) \right \rceil$. If $n > N$, then $4n+2 > \frac 3 \epsilon$, which implies $\epsilon > \frac{3}{4n+2}$, which implies $\left|\frac {3n}{2n+1} - \frac 32\right| < \epsilon$.

Therefore the sequence converges to $\frac 32$.